# Automorphism preserves irreducibility?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

There is a claim in my notes saying: If $D$ is an integral domain and $f:D[X]\to D[X]$ is an automorphism then $p(x)\in D[x]$ is irreducible iff $f(p(x))$ is irreducible. I have tried to prove this but I get stuck because I need to prove that $f$ sends constants to constants. Any help?

Comment: you don't need to prove that $f$ sends constants to constants, just that it sends units to units, which is not difficult

Comment: No, we don't define irreducibles that way. We define irreducible as a polynomial that can only be factored as a constant times something. I know that result is true.

Comment: @PedroGarcía so, according to your definition $2X\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is irreducible?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @PedroGarcía that's a really weird definition and generally speaking that's not how an irreducible polynomial (or, more generally, an irreducible element in some integral domain) is defined. Are you sure that your notes say "constant" and not "unit"?

Comment: Yes, the definition with units corresponds to something named "Atom"

Comment: @PedroGarcía yes, "atom" is another term for "irreducible element" (irreducible polynomial in your specific case). I think that in English this is definitely nonstandard terminology, but I believe that it is the common one in Romance languages.

Comment: You should check your definition of irreducible element again. Over a field they are equivalent, but it doesn't make much sense to call $2x$ an irreducible element in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ when it has a decomposition into non unit elements. This is something very non standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is unclear. By automorphism, do you mean $D$-algebra automorphism? If you do, then this is easy, because $f(1)=1$ and so for any $d \in D$, $f(d)=f(d \cdot 1)=d f(1)=d$, thus $f$ preserves constants.

If $f$ is just a ring automorphism, then this is false with the (non-standard) definition of irreducible polynomials you have provided in the comments.
Let $k$ be a field and let $D=k[Y]$, then we have a $k$-linear automorphism  $f:D[X] \to D[X]$ that sends $X \mapsto Y, Y \mapsto X$. Under this definition $X$ is irreducible, but $f(X)=Y$ is not irreducible, because it is constant. (If you define constants to be irreducible, then here's another example: $Y^2$ is irreducible, because it's constant, but $f(Y^2)=X^2$ is not irreducible.)